# spring boot Invalid bean definition with name 'WDSDataSource' defined in URL "

Tags: spring-boot

while executing the application getting invalid "WDSDataSource" in persistance.xml , could not resolve placeholder "AppEncryptionKey"

Below is snap of `persistence.xml` of wds configuration.

```
<bean id="WDSDataSource" class="com.deere.dsfj.utility.datasource.DSFJTomcatDataSource" init-method="initialize"
              p:username="${ApplicatinID}"
              p:encryptionKey="${AppEncryptionKey}"
              p:encryptionPassword="${AppEncryptedPassword}"       
              p:driverClassName="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"
              p:url="${WDSJdbcUrl}"
              p:testWhileIdle="false"
              p:testOnBorrow="true"
              p:testOnReturn="false"
              p:validationInterval="300000"
              p:timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="300000"
              p:maxActive="80"
              p:initialSize="0"
              p:maxWait="300000"
              p:removeAbandonedTimeout="300"
              p:minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="300000"
              p:minIdle="1"
              p:maxIdle="10"
              p:logAbandoned="true"
              p:removeAbandoned="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like spring is not able to find any value or the Key `AppEncryptionKey` in your properties file from which you are taking these values.

So ensure that the key `AppEncryptionKey` is present in the properties file.